# Is this possible to create differents UV Maps in one time?

Tags: mesh

I don't have much knowledge about UV Map and texturing, so I want to know if it's possible to take this mesh who has a loooot of differents parts:

[image]

and use "Smart UV Project" to have one map for all parts separately.
For now blender generates a big UV Map, so when I export my mesh to substance painter it's impossible to do something, my texture is horrible.

And make UV for all objects one by one will take me several hours.

Or if somebody has another best solution to texture this mesh please tell me :).

Thanks.

Comment: You can create up to 8 UVMaps for your meshes, but in this case it makes no sense. Just separate the model by assigning different materieals for each part and Smart UV one part at a time. Just use one UVMap and don't care about the different material's UVs overlap each other, it will work fine in Blender and SBP.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do that, thanks a lot !